# xslt 1.0 combinate two segments

Tags: xslt-1.0

how to combinate two or more segments to one segment at xslt 1.0?
I have two cases.

*Case1:*
If "QUALIFIER" at GRP/TXT is the same (for example: AAA) combinate this to one.

Correct:

QUALIFIER: AAA

TEXT: Test AAA rtetertertret

*Case2:*
Same should be at GRP/ITEM/TXT (for example: LIN)

Correct:

QUALIFIER: LIN

TEXT: Test LIN sdfsdfsfsf

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEEDELFOR>
 <Test/>
 <CNT>
  <TRANSMISSION_DATE></TRANSMISSION_DATE>
  <TRANSMISSION_TIME></TRANSMISSION_TIME>
  <INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER></INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER>
  <SENDER></SENDER>
  <SENDER_QUALIFIER></SENDER_QUALIFIER>
  <RECEIVER></RECEIVER>
  <RECEIVER_QUALIFIER></RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER></SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_VERSION></SYNTAX_VERSION>
  <BGM></BGM>
  <GRP>
   <IDENTIFIER_BY></IDENTIFIER_BY>
   <IDENTIFIER_SU></IDENTIFIER_SU>
   <DATE_4></DATE_4>
   <REF_ON></REF_ON>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER></NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER></NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER></NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <TXT>
    <QUALIFIER>AAA</QUALIFIER>
    <TEXT>Test AAA</TEXT>
   </TXT>
   <TXT>
    <QUALIFIER>AAA</QUALIFIER>
    <TEXT>rtetertertret</TEXT>
   </TXT>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA></ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT></QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>2</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <TXT>
    <QUALIFIER>LIN</QUALIFIER>
    <TEXT>Test LIN</TEXT>
   </TXT>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA></ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT></QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>1</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <TXT>
     <QUALIFIER>LIN</QUALIFIER>
     <TEXT>Test LIN</TEXT>
    </TXT>
    <TXT>
     <QUALIFIER>LIN</QUALIFIER>
     <TEXT>sdfsdfsfsf</TEXT>
    </TXT>
   </ITEM>
  </GRP>
 </CNT>
</SEEDELFOR>
```

Correct output should be:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SEEDELFOR>
 <Test/>
 <CNT>
  <TRANSMISSION_DATE></TRANSMISSION_DATE>
  <TRANSMISSION_TIME></TRANSMISSION_TIME>
  <INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER></INTERCHANGE_CONTROL_NUMBER>
  <SENDER></SENDER>
  <SENDER_QUALIFIER></SENDER_QUALIFIER>
  <RECEIVER></RECEIVER>
  <RECEIVER_QUALIFIER></RECEIVER_QUALIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER></SYNTAX_IDENTIFIER>
  <SYNTAX_VERSION></SYNTAX_VERSION>
  <BGM></BGM>
  <GRP>
   <IDENTIFIER_BY></IDENTIFIER_BY>
   <IDENTIFIER_SU></IDENTIFIER_SU>
   <DATE_4></DATE_4>
   <REF_ON></REF_ON>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER></NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER></NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
    <CONTACT>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <NUMBER></NUMBER>
    </CONTACT>
   </ADD>
   <ADD>
    <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
    <IDENTIFIER></IDENTIFIER>
    <AGENCY_CODE></AGENCY_CODE>
   </ADD>
   <TXT>
    <QUALIFIER>AAA</QUALIFIER>
    <TEXT>Test AAA rtetertertret</TEXT>
   </TXT>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
    <ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
     <QUALIFIER></QUALIFIER>
     <DETAILS></DETAILS>
    </ADDITIONAL_DETAILS>
   </TRANSPORT_DETAILS>
   <ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA></ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT></QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>2</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <TXT>
    <QUALIFIER>LIN</QUALIFIER>
    <TEXT>Test LIN</TEXT>
   </TXT>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
    <ITEM_NUMBER_SA></ITEM_NUMBER_SA>
    <QUANTITY></QUANTITY>
    <QUANTITY_UNIT></QUANTITY_UNIT>
    <LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>1</LINE_ITEM_NUMBER>
    <TXT>
     <QUALIFIER>LIN</QUALIFIER>
     <TEXT>Test LIN sdfsdfsfsf</TEXT>
    </TXT>
   </ITEM>
  </GRP>
 </CNT>
</SEEDELFOR>
```

Best regards
Julian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achievable as following in **XSLT 1.0**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:key name="qualifierKey" match="/SEEDELFOR/CNT/GRP//TXT" use="QUALIFIER" />
<xsl:key name="qualifierTextKey" match="/SEEDELFOR/CNT/GRP//TXT" use="concat(QUALIFIER, '|', TEXT)" />

<xsl:key name="itemTxtKey" match="/SEEDELFOR/CNT/GRP/ITEM/TXT" use="concat(generate-id(parent::*), QUALIFIER, '|', TEXT)" />

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TXT[position() &gt; 1]" />

<xsl:template match="/SEEDELFOR/CNT/GRP/ITEM/TXT[following-sibling::*[1]][generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('itemTxtKey', concat(generate-id(parent::*), QUALIFIER, '|', TEXT))[1])] 
                   | /SEEDELFOR/CNT/GRP/TXT[following-sibling::*[1]][generate-id() = generate-id(key('qualifierKey',QUALIFIER)[1])]">
    <TXT>
        <QUALIFIER>
            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(QUALIFIER)" />
        </QUALIFIER>
        <TEXT>
            <xsl:variable name="count" select="count(key('qualifierKey',QUALIFIER)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('qualifierTextKey', concat(QUALIFIER, '|', TEXT))[1])])" />
            <xsl:for-each select="key('qualifierKey',QUALIFIER)[generate-id() = generate-id(key('qualifierTextKey', concat(QUALIFIER, '|', TEXT))[1])]">

                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(TEXT)" />
                <xsl:if test="$count != position()"><xsl:value-of select="' '"></xsl:value-of></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </TEXT>
    </TXT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See output here: http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYib/2